# Can my Intel Atom run windows server 2008 R2

Tags: intel-atom

I just wonder if my old junk can run Windows Server 2008 R2. Its an netbook. Samsung N145-JP02, I own it for over few years and done an upgrade on it before. Thanks guys.

**System:**

- Intel Atom N450
- 2 GB Ram DDR2
- 80 GB of storage

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb414778.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows Server 2008 System Requirements
>
> Processor
>
> • Minimum: 1 GHz (x86 processor) or 1.4 GHz (x64 processor)
> • Recommended: 2 GHz or faster
>
> Note: An Intel Itanium 2 processor is required for Windows Server 2008
> for Itanium-Based Systems.
>
> Memory
> • Minimum: 512 MB RAM
> • Recommended: 2 GB RAM or greater
> • Maximum (32-bit systems): 4 GB (Standard) or 64 GB (Enterprise and
> Datacenter)
> • Maximum (64-bit systems): 32 GB (Standard) or 1 TB
> (Enterprise and Datacenter) or 2 TB (Itanium-Based Systems)
>
> Available Disk Space
>
> • Minimum: 10 GB
> • Recommended: 40 GB or greater
>
> Note: Computers with more than 16 GB of RAM will require more disk
> space for paging, hibernation, and dump files.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb414778.aspx